# Why doesn't my Refresh header work?

Tags: cgi

I'm working on a homework assignment in Perl CGI using the CGI.pm module. In my code I am checking for a cookie.  If the cookie exists, I want to initiate another CGI script.  In other situations I was able to use similar code, but in this instance I merely get the following browser output, not the redirect that I was looking for.

```
Refresh: 1; URL=homepage.pl.cgi
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Here's my code:

```
#get the cookie
my %SIDhash = cookie('SIDhash');

if ( exists $SIDhash{"SID"} ) {
    print header(-refresh=>'0; homepage.pl.cgi');
}
```

What fundamentals am I not understanding here?

Thanks,
CB

Comment: Is there a better way to initiate/switch to homepage.pl.cgi than what I am doing?  I am very open to suggestions as I am just learning perl cgi.

Comment: Where's the rest of the code? Is that the whole header your script outputs? Try reducing everything to the smallest example that solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
print header(
    -refresh => '0; url=homepage.pl.cgi',
    -cookie => $cookie,
);
```

If you are assembling the header in pieces, in various places in your code, save the header components in a variable first, e.g.:

```
my %headers;

# later...
$headers{-cookie} = $cookie;

# later still:
if (exists $SIDhash{SID})
{
    # we want to redirect, so print all headers and we're done.
    print header(%headers, -refresh => '0; url=homepage.pl.cgi');
    exit;
}

# if we're still here, nothing is printed yet.. continue preparing data and print when ready.
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks, as far as I can tell that did the trick and I learned a valuable lesson: only one header per page!  I appreciate everybody's thoughtful answers to my problem.  This project isn't complete yet so CGI experts, be ready for more! -cb

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the line to

```
print header(-refresh=>'0; url=homepage.pl.cgi');
```

From what I can tell, this should be correct now.

[This page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Refresh_Meta_tag_and_HTTP_refresh_header) offers information on Refresh and other methods of redirection.

Comment: That might be it now.  It's been a long time since I've manually written a refresh, so I looked up the syntax to make sure it was right.

Comment: no luck with that change either.  Would it matter that I've recently print header(-cookie=>$cookie) in the preceding code block?

Comment: That's probably it.  The header() function from CGI.pm ends it with a blank line, which signifies the end of the header to the browser.  There may be a way to buffer it so it doesn't send them until you're ready, but it's been awhile and I can't recall for sure.

Comment: That is definitely it, you should only print the header once.

Comment: Could you suggest a better way for my logic flow then?  My idea now is validate password/username in startPage.pl.cgi->set sessionID cookie->redirect into the homepage.pl.cgi 

suggestions anyone?

Comment: You might try storing your headers in a variable until you're sure you are ready to send them.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why your refresh doesn't work, but it sounds like it would be more appropriate to use:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.example.org/
```

Just a thought.

Comment: Okay, I attempted to replace the offending line with 
    print redirect('homepage.pl.cgi');
but no luck.
Now I just get:Status: 302 Moved Location: homepage.pl.cgi

Comment: A 307/Temporary redirect is probably more appropriate, but it still requires you to solve the duplicate header problem.

Comment: I disagree with the 307 due to the fact that it doesn't appear to be temporary, but rather an expected redirection.